# Calculus of real integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Complex Analysis by Cufi and Bruna has the following proposition on Page $194$:

> Suppose the $f$ is a meromorphic function on a neighbourhood of $H=\{z\colon Im \ z \geq 0 \}$, with a finite number of poles in $H$, none of them being real, and that $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} f(z)=0$. Then $p.v.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{ix} \ dx$ exists and $$p.v\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{ix} \ dx=2\pi i\sum_{\alpha} Res(f(z)e^{iz},\alpha)$$ where the sum is taken over the poles of $f$ located at $H$.

This is followed by the following example:

> Let $$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2}\ dx$$
>   In this case the principal value 
>   $$\lim_{r \to \infty}\int_0^r \frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac12 \lim_{r \to \infty}\int_{-r}^r \frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac 12 Im \lim_{r \to \infty}\int_{-r}^r \frac{xe^{ix}}{1+x^2}\ dx$$ exists. Actually, here $f(z)=\frac{z}{1+z^2} $ has a pole at the point $x=i$ with residue $\frac z{z+i} \mid_{z=i}=\frac12$ and it turns out that $$\lim_{r \to \infty}\int_0^r \frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac12 Im \ \pi i=\frac{\pi}2.$$

**Edit:** My question is that why in the example the author calculated the residue of $f(z)$ instead of $f(z)e^{iz}$ as in the statement of proposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the theorem you quoted contains this equality:

> $$p.v\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{ix} \ dx=2\pi i\sum_{\alpha} Res(f(z)e^{iz},\alpha)$$

Note the $f(x) e^{ix}$ in the integrand.  Since the integral you had (with irrelevant parts removed) was $\displaystyle \lim_{r \to \infty}\int_{-r}^r \frac{xe^{ix}}{1+x^2}\ dx,$ then $f(x)$ must be $\dfrac x{1+x^2}$.  Thus $f(z) = \dfrac z{1+z^2}$.

---

There is actually an error here.  This integral is actually equal to $\dfrac\pi{2e}$, not $\pi/2$.  It looks like they calculated the residue incorrectly.  It should indeed be:
$$ \lim_{z \to i} (z-i)\frac {ze^{iz}}{z^2+1} = \lim_{z\to i} \frac{ze^{iz}}{z+i} = \frac{ie^{i^2}}{2i} = \frac1{2e} $$
Put this into the formula and you'll get the correct result.

Comment: But in the right hand side we have $Res(f(z)e^{iz},\alpha)$.

Comment: @SahibaArora, the book is incorrect.  I'll update my answer..